# eb aws.push or eb deploy not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i have setup my rails application using `eb init` to deploy on amazon elastic bean but when i try to push the app using `eb aws.push` i got this error

```
git: 'aws.push' is not a git command. See 'git --help'
```

when i tried using `eb deploy` it shows this error

```
Creating application version archive "0_7_0-dev-915-g60d8".
ERROR: You cannot have more than 500 Application Versions. Either  
remove some Application Versions or request a limit increase.
```

then i found a fix for above error which is running this command `eb labs cleanup-versions` to clean up old application versions but it says

```
No application versions to delete.
```

what should i do to fix Applications Versions limit error ?

Answer (score -1):

You have to many application versions. You can manually delete application version using the AWS Console:

AWS Console / Elastic Beanstalk / *Your App* / Application Versions

- Select some obsolete versions and delete them.